# Odd behavior in a main file in c

Tags: c, header

I have a main.c file compiled successfully with dependencies.
The code of the main is:

```
#include "includer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i;
  printf("The value of argc is %d\n", argc);
  /*if (argc>1){
    printf("inside the if");
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
      assembler(argv[i]);
    }
  }*/
  printf("Now calling to testList");
  testList();
  /*printTable();*/
  return 0;
}
```

This is what "includer.h" looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include "datatypes.h"
```

When I run the main, I get the first `printf` on the screen, and then basically nothing happens, it looks as if it's running but it doesn't do anything, not even the second `printf`.

Can anyone point me to where the problem is, if there is one?

Comment: What happens if you add a new-line character to the second `printf` or print the string with `puts`?

Comment: `stdout` is normally line buffered by default, so if you forget to include a newline in your `printf`, you may not see it at all until a newline is printed elsewhere in your program, or until the program exits.

Comment: Try fflush(stdout) after each printf() call

Comment: Looks like the stdout buffer is not flushed.
You are saying that "basically nothing happens". However I believe that your code is executing properly even after second printf but you are not getting any feedback from printf.
This link might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: Just to clarify what's happening:  (1) The second `printf` *is* being executed, but the output is being buffered because there is no newline to cause it to be flushed, and (2) After the second `printf`, it's calling `testList` which apparently is never returning.

Comment: The buffer was the problem, solved now. Thanks...

Comment: stdout is line buffered by default when it is associated with a tty (or pseudo-tty).  If it is associated with a regular file, it is fully buffered by default.

Answer (score 3):

The `stdout` stream is buffered, so it will only display what's in the buffer after it reaches a newline (or when it's told to). You can force it to print by:

**Flushing `stdout`**

```
printf("Now calling to testList");
fflush(stdout);
testList();
```

**Disabling buffering on `stdout`**

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Apart from that your `testList()` call is never returning, which we can't help with since there's no code for it, causing your main to never *de facto*  'end' (meaning, reach your `return 0;`)

Comment: Bernard, I suggest to remove the `\n` so as to demonstrate when to use `fflush`. In your example `fflush` is not needed.

Comment: I think your example should be: `printf("Now calling to testList"); fflush(stdout);` Your current example don't need a flush

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You're right, didn't remember to take that off when I copied that line from OP's post.

Comment: @4386427 Nice idea, changed my answer.

Comment: If stdout is associated with a tty, then it is line-buffered by default.  If stdout is associated with a regular file, then its is fully buffered by default (meaning it is not necessarily this way).  If stdout is fully buffered, adding a newline won't cause the data to be written.